# How to display a embedded pdf file in Odoo?

Tags: report, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

I'm trying to do a documentation module where the user uploads a pdf file, and give a description about the file. so when you submit, you have the description, and the file. near the file there is a download button, that when you click on it it downloads the pdf file.

What I want to do is instead of downloading the file, just display the file in odoo. Well i tried something, i have created a qweb repot, and when you click the print button it will display a report in odoo (you just need the change the format of the print **Settings > Technical > Reports > Search** for your model name -> edit and change it to HTML.). But I have a problem, I don't know which tag I can use to display the pdf file (my logic is if you can display an image on report, maybe you can display a pdf file, so I've tried the "embed" tag but it's not working)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="report_doc">
              <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <div class="page">
                        <embed src="o.Document_binaire" width="800px" height="2100px" />
                    </div>
                    <p style="page-break-after:always"></p>
                </t>
           </t>
              </t>
        </template>
    </data>

</odoo>
```

So maybe there is another way to display a stored file in the database on Odoo. I'm waiting for your propositions and pieces of advice.

Comment: This boils down to a question about HTML

Comment: Do you mean that you want to embed the file within the default pdf viewer of the browser? Instead of downloading the file you can open it in a new tab. Is that enough for you? You can also attach documents to the record as attachments and then download them when you wish

Comment: Thank you ChesuCR that's what i have done.